# How do I convert a basic static site to dynamic so that I can give it a CMS? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to convert my static 5 page html site into a dynamic site so that I can add a CMS to it. I'd like to use PHP/MySQL for that. I want to keep the design so I don't want to use Wordpress.

I was trying to build a CMS from scratch since I know a little PHP/MySQL and I thought maybe that would be the best way since I already have the site designed with my own CSS and Jquery and have it exactly the way I want it.  And I don't mind learning a little in the process.

Should I go on building it from scratch or are there tools out there to help?  If I do build it from scratch do you know any tutorials that address this specific tasks (ie. converting an existing site into dynamic w/CMS) All of the tutorials I've seen are on building a site and CMS at the same time from scratch.  Or building a PHP/MySQL dynamic website for user input like blogs, forums etc

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using Wordpress

Comment: Ok thanks I didn't realize you could use wordpress as a CMS to your existing site layout.  I was under the impression you had to use one of their themes

Comment: Your impression is correct; I think what @SLaks was implying that since you're intending to migrate to a CMS, you might want to consider redoing the site as a WordPress site. You can make static pages ("Pages" as opposed to "Posts")

Comment: For future reference, might I suggest formatting your post slightly better? Paragraphs would go a long way in making this question more understandable. You can test formatting [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Ok.  I may do that in the future but this site was specifically set up to look a certain way.  Its a Graphic Designers site so even the structural HTML is part of his design that I wish to preserve

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I didn't realize it looked like that when I was typing it

Comment: When typing your question, there should be an area right underneath the text box that shows what your post will look like. It updates as you type too!

Comment: I shortened the question.  Can we reopen it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

https://www.cushycms.com/

http://www.lightcms.com/

Online CMS-services gives you a possibility to add a class to the parts of the page that you want to edit. Simple and basic. Or else i would go for a wordpress-site, and modify a template.

PS:
Extremly hard-to-read question. Make it shorter next time

Comment: This is better suited as a comment to the question.